# How to create two-row Header for ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My data is such that I want to display values for the Employee and the Supervisor for a particular record. Instead of describing it, I'll show you a rough example:

```
<table><tr>
<th colspan="3">Employee</th>
<th colspan="3">Supervisor</th>
</tr><tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Activity</th>
<th>Count</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Activity</th>
<th>Count</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I create this for a GridView?  I essentially want 2 rows for the headings, and some of the cells should span more than one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need the editing or sorting features of the gridview? I've found trying to do anything aside from display straight tabular data in the gridview is an exercise in patience.

For simplicity's sake I'd recommend using a repeater and writing your own table HTML if your grid is readonly.

**Editing**  to reply to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296904/how-to-create-two-row-header-for-asp-net-gridview#comment143686_296914) below.

> That may be the route we take, but for the purpose of mutual education I wonder if you could do such a thing with the GridView. – DLarsen

You can, but it is by no means easy. If you haven't already and you can afford to switch you may want to look at ASP.NET MVC, it gives you complete control of the HTML. You may want to check out this link about data-access in general. http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/ #15, #27, #51-53 may get you some ideas pertinent to your gridview issue.

Comment: That may be the route we take, but for the purpose of mutual education I wonder if you could do such a thing with the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by Galwegian, freezing data grid can be achieved by CSS expressions. But this works only on IE7 and below.

For versions above IE 7 and other browsers like Firefox, the snippet below should work.

```
function setWidth () {
    document.getElemenById("myDiv").style.left = body.clientWidth / 2 - oDiv.offsetWidth / 2;
    document.getElemenById("myDiv").style.top = document.body.clientHeight / 2 - oDiv.offsetHeight / 2;
}
```

Refer to http://techbookshelf.blogspot.in/2012/09/expressions-in-css.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to handle the RowDataBound and on the RowType for Header you set your own RenderMethod and write the HTML yourself.

```
e.Row.SetRenderMethodDelegate(New RenderMethod(AddressOf RenderHeader))
```